Minimizing expected regret for a bandit algorithm with a $R(T)$ upper bound.
I've tried solving the following question from Introduction to Multi-Armed Bandits by Professor Slivkins:
Take any bandit algorithm with an instance-independent regret bound $E[R(T)] \leq f(T)$, and construct an algorithm for pure-exploration bandits such that $E[\Delta(y_T)] \leq \frac{f(T)}{T}$.
My idea is to choose the arm with the highest empirical mean during a run. I first tried proving the case for $ K = 2 $, which I formulated as follows:
For $ K = 2 $, fix $ T $ and let $ \mu_1 > \mu_2 $. After $ T $ rounds, choose the arm with the highest empirical mean. Let us denote the chosen empirical mean by $\bar{\mu} $. I tried calculating the expected reward at each play as follows:
$$
E_r = p_1 q_1 + p_2 q_2,
$$
where $ p_1 > 0.5 $ (I was only able to prove this in the asymptotic case where $ T \to \infty $ However, this results in the expected regret:
$$
E[\Delta(y_T)] = 1 - p_1 q_1 - p_2 q_2,
$$
which doesn't seem to allow me to prove the $ \frac{f(T)}{T} $ bound. The expected reward falls somewhere between $ \mu_1 $ and $ \mu_2 $, but that doesn’t provide much useful information.
My next idea was to calculate $ p_1 $ based on the expected occurrences of the arms with means $ \mu_1 $ and $ \mu_2 $, denoted by $ n_1 $ and $ n_2 $, respectively, and then use that to bound the immediate regret. However, I haven’t been able to work this out.
Any hints or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Play according to the low-regret algorithm. At the end, pick the output arm randomly, with probability of picking $k$ equal to $N_k(T)/T$ (where $N_k(T)$ is the number of times the arm $k$ was chosen). Then the expected gap is $\mathbb{E}[\sum_k \Delta_k N_k(T)/T],$ but $\mathbb{E}[\sum_k \Delta_k N_k(T)]$ is just the expected regret, so this is $\le f(T)/T$.
